# Log hard drive temperature at regular intervals

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, temperature

One of our old computers is restarting randomly after some hours. I suspect the hard drive overheats. Is there a way to log the hard drive temperature every hour?

Comment: Did you googlized any mointoring tools before you asked your question here?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a hacky solution but you can throw together something with smartctl, a batch file  and windows task scheduler

I'm using a copy of [smartctl from a portable install of gsmartctl](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home)

First determine the devices on the system and work out their names. Smartctl uses the 'unix' style of naming drives

`smartctl -scan` will output all the drives on the system

```
c:\Users\me> smartctl.exe --scan /dev/sda -d ata # /dev/sda, ATA device
```

Then you can dump all information on that drive with

```
smartctl.exe -a /dev/sda
```

You can then direct that to a file with

```
smartctl.exe -a /dev/sda >> foo
```

Wrap it up with a batch script (perhaps using grep to sort out the drive temperature) and run it with scheduled tasks and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 1):

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) can log temperatures to a file.

Once you have SpeedFan up and running, do the following:

1. In the main screen, click **Configure**.
2. Under the **Temperatures** tab, select the entry that corresponds to your hard drive (Probably `HD0`, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename) and check the "Logged" checkbox at the bottom. Repeat for every temperature you want to log.
3. Under the **Log** tab, select "Enabled" and customise the options if you wish.
4. Click **OK**.
5. Done. Logs (in CSV format) will appear in the directory that you installed SpeedFan to.

Alternatively, [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com) is another utility that can log component temperatures to a file.